# How to avoid DEADLINE_EXCEEDED parsing firestore database to send push notifications?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications to 10 000+ tokens stored in Firestore.
Each time, I got a DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error.
I have already updated the timeout to 300s.

I don't know how to improve my code to avoid this error.

```
const pagination = 200;

function parseAndSend(push) {

    const parse = async(request, total) => {

            let snapshot = await request.get();
            
            let lastVisible = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length-1];
            let length = snapshot.size;
    
            var users= {};

            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
               pushHelperFunctions.addUsers(doc, users);
            });

            pushHelperFunctions.sendMessage(users, push);

            if(length < pagination) {

                return console.log("finish", total+length);

            } else {

                let next = admin.firestore().collection("users").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(pagination);

                return parse(next, total+length);

            }

    }

    return parse(admin.firestore().collection("users").limit(pagination), 0);
}


async function sendMessage(users, push) {

  Object.keys(users).forEach(key => {

      if (users[key].length > 0) {
        
            let message = payloads.setMessage(users[key], key, push);

            // Send notifications to all tokens.
            admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message).then(response => {
                console.log(response.successCount + " messages were sent successfully");

                cleanupTokens(response, users[key]);
                
                return true;

            }).catch(error => {
                mailer.sendMail("messaging().sendToDevice - Error sending message "+push);
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                return false;
            });

      }

        
  });

}


// Cleans up the tokens that are no longer valid.
function cleanupTokens(response, tokens) {
    // For each notification we check if there was an error.

     if (response.failureCount > 0) {

        const tokensDelete = [];
        const failedTokens = [];
        response.responses.forEach((resp, index) => {

          if (!resp.success) {
            failedTokens.push(tokens[index]);

            const deleteTask = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(tokens[index]).delete();
            tokensDelete.push(deleteTask);
          }
       
        });

        console.log('List of tokens that caused failures: ' + failedTokens);

        return Promise.all(tokensDelete);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also I don't find a way to test my code without sending a prod message to my users... It makes testing difficult.

Comment: It sounds like you'll have to split the sending into batches of messages.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have already split the sending, I send 200 pushes at a time.

Comment: Do you still need help with this issue?

Comment: yes, not solved yet

Comment: Even you splitted the sending into batches you are getting the same error, right? Since it is not possible to do that with one send batch.

Comment: Yep absolutely!

Comment: As per this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices "The REST API and the Admin FCM APIs allow you to multicast a message to a list of device registration tokens. You can specify up to 100 device registration tokens (500 for Java and Node.js) per invocation." Also here you can find how to batch messages https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages